# Printing really long prints on Epson Thermal Printers

Tags: printing, thermal-printer, epson

Working on a project where I'm printing really long prints on epson thermal printers (80mm x 18000mm) (length is variable per print).

My documents are set up as 1000mm long pages ie 14000mm print is 14 pages.

I'm able to print a correct length document with this command

```
lp -d 10_0_0_11 -o media=Custom.80x18000mm -o PageSize=Custom.80x1000mm -o TmtPaperSource=DocNoFeedCut -o landscape -o fit-to-page -o outputorder=reverse -o TmtSpeed=1 -o TmtPaperReduction=Both example/url/to/document
```

But this is really slow and don't want to use the command line for convenience.

When printing the document via Preview MacOS it only prints a portion of the document at the printer's max print size of 80x297mm. I have a custom page size of 80x1000mm setup but it seems to be ignoring that.

Any better workaround to gain the extra speed printing without the command line?

Comment: If you need various Mac fonts, text decoration, point-by-point sizing, print orientation rotation, graphical representation, etc., there is no other way. Create an ESC/POS control sequence directly if you can tolerate poor print results that can be obtained with one type of built-in font that the printer has, limited decoration, a size specified by an integral multiple of the font, and a monochrome bit image. It may be possible to reduce the data size and speed up printing by sending.